# Celery restart loss scheduled tasks

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I use Celery to schedule the sending of emails in the future. I put the task in celery with apply_async() and ETA setted sometimes in the future.

When I look in flower I see that all tasks scheduled for the future has status RECEIVED.

If I restart celery all tasks are gone. Why they are gone?

I use redis as a broker.

**EDIT1**

In documentation I found:

> If a task is not acknowledged within the Visibility Timeout the task will be redelivered to another worker and executed.
>
> This causes problems with ETA/countdown/retry tasks where the time to execute exceeds the visibility timeout; in fact if that happens it will be executed again, and again in a loop.
>
> So you have to increase the visibility timeout to match the time of the longest ETA you are planning to use.
>
> Note that Celery will redeliver messages at worker shutdown, so having a long visibility timeout will only delay the redelivery of ‘lost’ tasks in the event of a power failure or forcefully terminated workers.
>
> Periodic tasks will not be affected by the visibility timeout, as this is a concept separate from ETA/countdown.
>
> You can increase this timeout by configuring a transport option with the same name:
>
> BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 43200}
>
> The value must be an int describing the number of seconds.

But the ETA of my tasks can be measured in months or years.

**EDIT 2**

This is what I get when I type:

> $ celery -A app inspect scheduled
>
> {u'priority': 6, u'eta': u'2015-11-22T11:53:00-08:00', u'request': {u'args': u'(16426,)', u'time_start': None, u'name': u'core.tasks.action_du
> e', u'delivery_info': {u'priority': 0, u'redelivered': None, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'exchange': u'celery'}, u'hostname': u'celery@app.myplanmap.com', u'ack
> nowledged': False, u'kwargs': u'{}', u'id': u'8ac59984-f8d0-47ae-ac9e-c4e3ea9c4a
> c6', u'worker_pid': None}}

If you look closely, task wasn't acknowledged yet, so it should stay in redis after celery restart, right?

Answer (score 3):

you have to use RabbitMq instead redis.

RabbitMQ is feature-complete, stable, durable and easy to install. It’s an excellent choice for a production environment.

Redis is also feature-complete, but is more susceptible to data loss in the event of abrupt termination or power failures.

Using rabbit mq your problem of lossing message on restart have to gone.

Comment: almost 3 years later u.u